# Do pregnancies apply at the Bawdyhouse?

Tags: en-garde

These is a chance to get your mistress (or wife) pregnant during each "romantic encounter".  At a Bawdyhouse you can purchase female companionship.  Are you able to get a female companion pregnant at a Bawdyhouse, or does that only apply to missresses and wives?

Comment: Another great example of a question that makes you arch your brow when you simply see the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only mistresses and wives are mentioned in [pregnancy](http://patriot.net/~aquazoo/eg/eg_rules/eg_env.html#preg), so looks like you're safe there!

Comment: Presumably purchased companionship has some primitive pharmaceutical method of avoiding pregnancy.

Comment: They lack both uteruses and souls.

Comment: Or you can houserule it in since that does seem an oversight, and enjoy the sociopolitics of illegitimate children…

Comment: @SevenSidedDie How would they even know who the father was? It's not like a noblewoman where there are maybe a handful of possible candidates...

Comment: @Melon The most narratively-interesting/inconvenient possibility is who they declare is the father, of course.

Comment: This actually sparked some great debate in a game of 7th Sea I sat in on.  The GM had deemed that a female character *in the party* had gotten pregnant and the debate was whether or not this took away from the game as a source of fantasy.

Comment: From a verisimilitude perspective: early modern STDs resulted in general infertility amongst women who habitually sold sex, particularly amongst women confined in places where sex was sold.  (We'd think of them as prostitutes and brothels, but I'm less sure about the anachronism of that comparison over time).  @SevenSidedDie &Melon in en-garde paternity is declared for mistresses based on primary lover regardless of coitus.  &Oblivious Sage historically STD infertility was "birth control"